# C# connection with MS access is not working?

Tags: c#, database, windows

When I start debugging and I add some clients, I can add them, update them and read them. But the newly added clients won't save in my database. I've checked if I'm using the right file location and I am:

```
public class DBaccess
{

    private static string connectionstr;

    static DBaccess()
    {
        string mdffile;
        mdffile = @"C:\Users\rik\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Week-2-Opdracht\Database\Clienten.accdb";

        connectionstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + mdffile + ";";

    }

    public static DataSet Getwaardenquery(string sqlstr)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Console.WriteLine(sqlstr);
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);

        OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, con);
        dap.Fill(ds);
        return ds;

    }

    public static int Uitvoerenquery(string sqlstr)
    {
        int resultaat = -1;
        Console.WriteLine(sqlstr);

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            resultaat = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            string x = exp.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return resultaat;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you stated "won't save". Where is the "save" code? or at least the sqlstr...

Comment: "NOT WORKING ?" what error do you get?

Comment: Don't swallow your exception like that.  You want to know what it says.

Comment: The problem is that i dont get an error. but still the database doesnt connects because i cant add something into it or get information from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first check your connection string is correct or not by making a manual connection.
For help follow the given link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8d90a/connect-oledb-database-in-C-Sharp-in-easy-steps/

Answer (score 0):

your code contain extra semicolon

```
connectionstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + mdffile + "'";
```

syntax error